# Can I return bash function while being in sed?

Tags: sed

Can I return bash function while being in sed?

```
foo() {
 sed ... label: 'NEED TO RETURN foo() HERE' ...
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use a label and a goto to exit your sed script, and then that will return to foo().

http://www.gnu.org/software/sed/manual/sed.html#Programming-Commands